# Apps script throwing error at create text finder variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using the google "Apps Script" extension on a sheets document. I am attempting to create a script that would check two lists against each other. This script would take two pages in the same google sheet, compare matching rows by content in cell E which would be a service address ie. 123 Main St., find it in sheet B which could be in a different row. To do this I need a text finder variable. However just introducing this:
`var textFinder = nl2.createTextFinder("a");` 
I am getting an error code. It has been awhile since I have touched java script but google seems to have failed me. I will post the full code and error below.

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  //var sh3=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3'); //Might need to copy & paste to another sheet the differences 


//Finding the longest sheet so I am not searching for new values in the old sheet
  var nl1=sh1.getRange(1, 1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var nl2=sh2.getRange(1, 1,sh2.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var d=0;


//Create the new text finder
  var textFinder = nl2.createTextFinder("a");

//Makes sure that I'm not searching for new variables in an older list.
  if(nl1.length>nl2.length) {
    var lA=nl1.slice();
    var sA=nl2.slice();
  }else if(nl2.length>nl1.length){
    var lA=nl2.slice();
    var sA=nl1.slice();
  }else if(nl1.length==nl2.length) {
    return [];
  } 

//Load bearing loop
  for(var i=0;i<lA.length;i++) {
    if(sA.indexOf(lA[i-d])>-1) {


    // Returns the first occurrence of 'a'.
    var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext();
    var numOccurrencesReplaced = textFinder.replaceWith('!'); 

      lA.splice(i-d++,1)
    }
  }
}
```

**The error I am receiving is:**
Error
TypeError: nl2.createTextFinder is not a function
myFunction  @ TDC.gs:15

Comment: CreateTextFinder "needs" a range, sheet or spreadsheet to find the text. Your nl2 is just an array. A range in google sheets is an array of arrays. Omit the .map after your getValues()  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder?hl=en

Comment: @RamónLópezdeAndújar
I did this: 
` var nl1=sh1.getRange(1, 1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var nl2=sh2.getRange(1, 1,sh2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var d=0;`
And still received the same error: TypeError: nl2.createTextFinder is not a function